# Alter Table Column Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, alter-table

I needed to create a table with dynamic columns, so I created a cursor that loops through the records of a table and will create the necessary columns, however, is giving me this error:

Incorrect syntax near 'INT'.

Example code:

```
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #temp3 ADD ' + @nome + ' INT'
EXEC (@sql);
```

I have also tried this:

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #temp3 ADD ' + @nome + ' INT')
```

But still the same error

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
Examples of values ​​that can receive @nome

- Very Bad
- Bad
- Good
- Very Good

Comment: Without knowing what `@nome` contains, it's anyones guess. As well as/instead of `EXEC`ing the constructed string, try `PRINT`ing it as well, so you can see what's being run.

Comment: whats the value set in variable `@nome`?

Comment: And my other recommendation would be: try harder to come up with a solution that doesn't need dynamic columns - maybe it's just a presentation issue that can be better dealt with at a non-database layer.

Comment: can't fin the reference but the exec execution environment does not know about temporary table.

Comment: @tschmit007 - not true. Within the scope of the `exec`, you can reference temp tables created in the outer scope. Maybe you're thinking of table *variables*

Comment: Sorry guys... @nome is a cursor that reads data from a table.
Examples of values ​​that can receive @ name

Very Bad
Bad
Good
Very Good

I will edit and put this information.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you seems to be rights, I post an answer to illustrate my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've indicated that `@nome` may contain, for instance, Very Bad. If that is so, it contains a space - you need to delimit the name so that SQL Server knows that the space is part of the name:

```
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #temp3 ADD [' + @nome + '] INT'
EXEC (@sql);
```

or more properly, use [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

```
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #temp3 ADD ' + QUOTENAME(@nome) + ' INT'
EXEC (@sql);
```

Otherwise, SQL Server is trying to add a column called `Very` with a datatype of `Bad`, and it doesn't even know how to interpret `int` after that.

Comment: Apparently the problem is solved. But I'll do some tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Damien that encourage me to investigate:

```
if object_id(N'#tempg') is not null
    drop table #tempg

select 1 as i into #tempg

select * from #tempg

alter table #tempg add j int

exec sp_executesql N'alter table #tempg add k int'

select * from #tempg
```

note that

```
exec 'alter table #tempg add l int'
```

fails with

```
Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 1
Syntaxe incorrecte vers 'alter table #tempg add l int'.
```

=============================================
Edition

```
exec ('alter table #tempg add l int')
```

runs

Comment: That only produces an error because to `exec` a literal string, you have to use `EXEC()` with `()` bracketing the string. `exec object` works for executing stored procedures.

Comment: without the parenthesis sql thinks it is a procedure